# Webservices - Getting Started

Tags: php, web-services, integration, system

I need to learn about webservices. Where should I start. What's the pattern used today? SOAP, WSDL, i've read about it without understand. What are they? Is there a pattern used today to build Webservices? What's obsolete?
Thank you.

Comment: extremely broad, start with google.

Comment: sorry, i've read about but i don't get it yet

Comment: SOAP, WSDL, XML, JSON - basically all accomplish the same thing - it's a matter of what works for your project.

Answer (score 0):

all of this is for communicating between application in separated environment in the safe and secure mode without dependency to platform and rollback with xml in my opinion you can start with this resources:

http://cdsweb.u-strasbg.fr/meeting1/SOAPTutorial.pdf

i leaned it by this pdf

**PHP_5_Power_Programming.pdf**

Comment: if you want i can mail some of this resources to you